# Extracting fields from a string in JSON array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am very new to snowflake. I have queried some JSON data in snowflake  , though the below has a long string "metadata' in my JSON array from which I need to extract a few fields from the following JSON object.

```
{

  "metaData": "code:VALID_ERROR,message: the provided credentials

  were not correct,type: ITEM_ERROR,exit_status: null,action_id: dax_123,

  action_name: Queentech,

  session_id: 678-902-6y78,type: null,

  name: null,timestamp: 2020-07-11T20:52:59.158Z,timestamp_epoch_sec: 1594500779",

  "statusId": "3478-901fg-u9710"
}
```

I gave this object the alias `header`.
I have tried

```
select header:statusId::varchar as statusid,
header.metadata.code ::varchar as code,
header.metadata.message::varchar as message 
from test 
where header:status_id ='3478-901fg-u9710'
```

I get NUll values for code and message . Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!
Tara Palmer

}::variant as payload

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following and it works. You have the column name incorrect. I don't see any status_id

```js
WITH X AS (
  SELECT PARSE_JSON($1) AS header
    FROM VALUES ($$
{
"metaData": "code:VALID_ERROR,message: the provided credentials were not correct,type: ITEM_ERROR,exit_status: null,action_id: dax_123,action_name: Queentech,session_id: 678-902-6y78,type: null,name: null,timestamp: 2020-07-11T20:52:59.158Z,timestamp_epoch_sec: 1594500779",
"statusId": "3478-901fg-u9710" }
$$)
)
select header:statusId::varchar as statusid
,header:metaData:code ::varchar as code
,header:metadata.message::varchar as message 
from X 
where header:statusId::varchar = '3478-901fg-u9710'
  
;
```

EDIT: Following snippet only flatten the header and metadata columns. It does not return the results as in original query. But this query can be extended

```js
--Following Json is in correct format
create or replace table sample_json as
  SELECT PARSE_JSON($1) AS header
    FROM VALUES ($$
{
"metaData": "{code:'VALID_ERROR',message: 'the provided credentials were not correct'}",
"statusId": "3478-901fg-u9710" }
$$)
;


  select ,
  g.path , g.value
 from sample_json c,
   lateral flatten(input => header) f
,      lateral flatten(input => parse_json(f.value)) g
where  f.key = 'metaData'
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! The code and message using the above code still displays NULL 's instead of the actual value.

Comment: The above script is not flattened as the metaData column is also a variant. I have edited my answer with flattened json

Comment: Thank you Iqra Ijaz. Your code work well if the data is in the below format: 
{
"metaData": "code:VALID_ERROR,message: the provided credentials were not correct,type: ITEM_ERROR,exit_status: null,action_id: dax_123,action_name: Queentech,session_id: 678-902-6y78,type: null,name: null,timestamp: 2020-07-11T20:52:59.158Z,timestamp_epoch_sec: 1594500779",
"statusId": "3478-901fg-u9710" }

Comment: I am not getting the results as my data is in different format: There are no curly brackets after the metadata.
{
"metaData": "code:VALID_ERROR,message: the provided credentials were not correct,type: ITEM_ERROR,exit_status: null,action_id: dax_123,action_name: Queentech,session_id: 678-902-6y78,type: null,name: null,timestamp: 2020-07-11T20:52:59.158Z,timestamp_epoch_sec: 1594500779",
"statusId": "3478-901fg-u9710" }

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow and Snowflake! The [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html) can help figure out how to query a VARIANT column with a JSON object. Two questions you need to answer first:

1. Is the JSON in your table stored as text? If so, you will need to call PARSE_JSON() on the field.
2. Are you attempting to query a nested array? If so, you will need to use FLATTEN() on that field.

Make sure you understand how to answer those two questions before troubleshooting what you have. It will make the troubleshooting process easier. When you query an object in JSON, the "metadata" field in you call it with `header:field_you_want`. Notice there is a single colon inbetween the fields. If you want something further down a path, periods can be used. `header:field_you_want.some_value`

So your query cleaned up would look more like the following:

```
select header:statusId as statusid,
header:metadata.code as code,
header:metadata.message as message 
from test 
where header:status_id ='3478-901fg-u9710'
```